# which EFI record was used for Linux run

Tags: linux, linux-mint, efi

I have a two disks (WIn10 and Linux Mint ), both disks have EFI partition but Windows disk EFI contains a records for WIn10 as well as for Mint.
How can I check (on running Mint) which EFI was used for the start?

Comment: This is why I dislike dual boot installs to separate drives; which EFI did you touch?

Comment: I'm no expert with EFI, however, from what I understand is that Windows Bootloader starts and allows you to choose the Linux operating system, this shifts the command to Linux which starts from it's own EFI.

Comment: when I was installing linux mint , I've added new physical drive into my PC, and I've created own (new drive) EFI partition and specified to use this drive partition for linux boot loader. however , when I have a choice (BIOS) what should be loaded , there are three options - win10 and two linux mint (with no difference in the menu item) .

Comment: I suppose that one of "linux mint" records kept from old installation linux on the same drive. so need to clarify what is what and clean unused